# Preventing NGINX from buffering packages

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I need to modify the topic of MQTT publish packages using NGINX proxy. I created a njs function which is called by js_filter.

```
function updateTopic(s) {
  s.log("buf: " + s.buffer.toString('hex'));

  if (!s.fromUpstream) {
    if(s.buffer.indexOf("topic") != -1){
      s.buffer = s.buffer.replace("topic", "mopic").toBytes();
      s.log("new buffer: " + s.buffer.toString('hex'));
    }

  }

  return s.OK;
}
```

returns:

> buf: 300f0005746f7069636d65737361676533
>
> new buffer: 300f00056d6f7069636d65737361676533

This function updates s.buffer correctly, but the packages are not transmitted until another type of package is received. When a subscribe, disconnect, ping message is received, all the buffered messages are transmitted at once.

If this function does not replace a package, it is transmitted instantaneously.

Should I do something special after changing s.buffer?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be due to a bug, which will be fixed in later versions.

https://github.com/nginx/njs/issues/45